# Machine learning online course recommendation for self-studying?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for more machine learning online self-study materials. I have taken Andrew's [CS229 course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGwO_UgTS7I&list=PLoROMvodv4rMiGQp3WXShtMGgzqpfVfbU&ab_channel=StanfordOnline), and participated few Kaggle competitions and found that they are very good self-studying materials, and love them very much.

I want to go deeper into math and, at the same time, train myself to apply machine learning techniques well in more real-world problem practice (like Kaggle competitions and research). Books or projects are welcome as well!

I really appreciate all of your suggestions!